# C++: this-pointer overwritten

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault, x11

Please take a look at my source files, they're a bit too long to post them here:

`X11Painter.cpp: http://pastebin.com/gu4SrHUr`

`X11Painter.h: http://pastebin.com/3ktp1Fvn`

The behaviour of this class is in my opinion **very strange**.

I'm having the following test case:

```
#include "X11Painter.h"
int main()
{
    X11Painter p ;
    p.show();
}
```

Compiling it with the line

```
g++ -O0 -g -o test2 test2.cpp X11Painter.cpp -lX11 -lXfixes -lXinerama
```

and simply running it does the following:

```
this->some_test=1234
this->screen:0
1:: this->display='0x8b73008'; this->window='77594625'
width: 3200
0xbff91bdc
this->some_test=1234
this->some_test=3682292
Segmentation fault
```

I'm trying to map the X11 window in `X11Painter::show()`

When I started investigating why X11Painter.cpp:83 is segfaulting, I found out that most of the variables are overwritten and completely different in `show()` than they were in the constructor.

I put the `int some_test` to see what's happening. Why the hell is the value changing?

If I do `printf("%p\n", this)`, the pointer also changes. I suspect that somewhere, the this-pointer is overwritten. But why is this happening? Debugging with ddd told me that this->some_value is modified right while exiting the constructor.

Doing a short test with a testclass (class with a public constructor, one public method and one private variable) works without any problem.

Does anybody have an idea why this strange thing is happening?
I know what happens to variables lieing on the stack, but we're still in main there...

Might it be related to the X11-libraries?

Comment: You should make your source files small enough to post here. This has two advantages: firstly, more people will see them; secondly, in the process of making them smaller, you might find the source of the problem yourself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your parameterless constructor, you do this

```
X11Painter::X11Painter()
{
    X11Painter(-1);
}
```

This is not doing what you think it is doing, since there is no constructor chaining in C++. What the code above is doing is constructing a temporary `X11Painter` object, calling the other constructor for that temporary object, but not actually initializing anything in the object you want to construct.

To fix this but retain the same behavior, remove your parameterless constructor and in your `.h` file declare the other constructor as

```
X11Painter(int screenno = -1);
```

This will default the `screenno` argument to `-1` if you do not supply one.

Comment: +1 for pointing out an error, but two remarks: 1. In the next C++ version there will be constructor chaining, albeit with a different syntax. 2. The constructor should be declared `explicit` since an implicit conversion from `int` to `X11Painter` makes no sense.

Comment: Philipp: What do you exactly mean with the 2nd remark ? Where is a conversion from int to X11Painter? thanks

Comment: @Atmocreations: If you have a one-parameter constructor, like in this case, it allows an implicit conversion from the parameter type to the object type. Here it would mean that you could use an `int` where an `X11Painter` is expected and the constructor would be called to do the conversion. Declaring the constructor `explicit` prevents this implicit type conversion.

Comment: @Philipp: After having read some documentation, I finally understand your thought. Something one really have to pay attention to. Thanks!

Comment: @jk [Accept]: Great answer. Thank you! Tried as suggested and it works. Learned yet another important thing about how you can shoot yourself in the foot :P

Answer (score 1):

This looks to me like stack corruption, most likely arising through the

```
        Window                  window;
        XSetWindowAttributes    winattr;
```

members, as the others are all primitive types. For example, I noticed this:

```
    XStoreName(this->display, this->window, "LaserFinger");
```

If the window and display don't have the correct amount of memory, this could go kaboom.
However without knowing the X11 libraries, I can't be of much more help.

Comment: This is actually correct. These functions are intended to use that way. Window is in the end an unsigned long and Display is a struct. But thanks for pointing it out.